# How to translate an object to a location slowly (so that it can be seen)

Tags: java, math, trigonometry, translate, direction

In my game I have a player object and an enemy object. The enemy object, when initialized is supposed to find the current location of the player at that specific time and head towards that spot, ultimately passing or hitting the player at which point it'll go offscreen.

In order to do this I've figured I'm going to have to use trigonometry however I can't seem to figure out what to do as my equation for direction and speed never aligns with the position of the player.

Here's what I have..

```
    direction = Math.atan((this.X_POS-plr.X_POS)/(this.Y_POS-plr.Y_POS));

    speedX = (int) (speed * Math.cos(direction));
    speedY = (int) (speed * Math.sin(direction));
```

- "this" is the enemy and "plr" is the player.
- "direction" is the angle to the player
- "speedX" and "speedY" is the amount to translate each game tick. (deltaX, deltaY)

Here's my rough notes if it helps:

[image]

If anyone has any idea how to properly do this I'd appreciate the help, thanks!

```
    //Inside the food/enemy class:
    //inside the constructor
    direction = Math.random() * 2.0 * Math.PI; //x/y position of player, xy position of food
    direction = Math.atan((this.X_POS-plr.X_POS)/(this.Y_POS-plr.Y_POS));

    speedX = (int) (speed * Math.cos(direction));
    speedY = (int) (speed * Math.sin(direction));

    //inside update position method
    X_POS += speedX;
    Y_POS += speedY;

    //inside draw player method
    g.setColor(rim);
    g.fillOval(X_POS-radius-3, Y_POS-radius-3, (radius*2)+6, (radius*2)+6);

    g.setColor(center);
    g.fillOval(X_POS-radius, Y_POS-radius, radius*2, radius*2);  

   //Inside the player class X_POS and Y_POS are set to 200 each.
```

Then, inside the run method of the main class every 15 milseconds the update position method and draw method is called.

Comment: What is your *specific* problem? Figure out how many ticks you want the translation to take, and do 1/N of the translation in each tick. You don't need any trigonometry to do this. If the enemy starts at (200,100) and you are at (150,150) and it's to take 10 ticks, then the enemy needs to move at a rate of (-5,5) each tick. No trig required, just simple division of X and Y separately.

Comment: Because it's not supposed to stop once it reaches the target. There's no specific amount of ticks it's supposed to take to get there, it'll be different depending on where the enemy spawns at it'll be able to from any location. For example, open this up and imagine the dots go straight towards your cursor..

http://www.polkadotgame.com

Comment: cAN you post your entire code in pastebin and link here .

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HQBeMx8m - enemy/food class

Comment: http://pastebin.com/itjka8Yv - main class

Comment: Very few people here have to time to sort through the entirety of your program. [Slim it down into something that encapsulates your problem and nothing more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then show us what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I'll throw it in the main question.

Comment: The request for more code was pointless. The issue was clearly visible in the code in the original post. Adding more doesn't help and can hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since nobody else seems to know how I found out how myself.

```
    direction = Math.atan2(plr.Y_POS - Y_POS, plr.X_POS - X_POS);

    speedX = (speed * Math.cos(direction));
    speedY = (speed * Math.sin(direction));
```

Thanks for the help!